# Remove row from dataframe if two columns not in certain range

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
COLA COLB COLC COLD COLE
A    10   300  30   240
B    0    1000 1200 1400
C    50   120  50   120
D    40   300  10   150
E    30   47   30   58
```

and the idea is to remove each row where the COLD-COLE range is not in the COLB-COLC range

and then the output would be:

```
COLA COLB COLC COLD COLE
A    10   300  30   240
C    50   120  50   120
```

where for exemple `B` is removed because `1200-1400` is not in the range `0 - 1000` 
etc

Comment: What is COL2 here?

Comment: oups, I modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = {
        "COLA": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
        "COLB": [10, 0, 50, 40, 30],
        "COLC": [300, 1000, 120, 300, 47],
        "COLD": [30, 1200, 50, 10, 30],
        "COLE": [240, 1400, 120, 150, 50],
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    result = df[((df.COLD >= df.COLB) & (df.COLE <= df.COLC))]
    print(result)
```